# Excel Automation Using Pyautogui

Tags: python, excel, pyautogui, hotkeys

I have an excel plugin that I need to refresh on 4000 excel files. The shortcut to refresh is "Alt + s + r + a". I want to run a loop where I open the excel file, perform the refresh using the shortcut, and then save the excel file. Here is my code for one excel file:

```
import pyautogui
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/file.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 's', 'r', 'a')
wb.save("C:/file.xlsx")
```

However this just opens and saves the excel file without refreshing it. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is S ('alt', 's', 'r', 'a')? S is not available in my spreadsheet. can you point me the menu bar?

Comment: Its an excel plugin for factset:

Comment: I tried to screen shot a picture but it isn't working. Its a shortcut for the FactSet Add-in in Excel

Comment: hey these shoutcut keys will only work if excel sheet is opened.

Comment: Is there a way to open it in python, perform the shortcut, and then save it?

Comment: I have posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used win32com to open excel and bring it to the top and start pressing the buttons one by one with a 1-second delay, then save and closes it.

```
import time
import pyautogui
import win32com.client
from win32gui import SetForegroundWindow
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open("C:/file.xlsx")
xl.Visible = True
SetForegroundWindow(xl.hwnd)
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.typewrite(['alt', 's', 'r', 'a'], interval=1)
time.sleep(3)
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Quit()
```